# How to remove every part, except the end from elements in a list in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a problem to edit remove every part, except the end, of every elements in a list.
The list looks like this at the beginning:

```
['/dev/sda1', '/dev/sdb1', '/dev/sdc1', '/mnt/xxx/yyy']
```

Now i want to edit it, so i only have the last part of every element left.
So the list should be look like this at the end:

```
['/sda1', '/sdb1', '/sdc1', '/yyy']
```

I wanted to loop through this list and edit every element but i don't know how i can regex this.
Does anybody has an idea?
Thanks for everybody who look at this!

Comment: Use ``my_list|(map('regex_replace', ...)``. If you have a problem [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_list|map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|list }}"
      vars:
        my_list: ['/dev/sda1', '/dev/sdb1', '/dev/sdc1', '/mnt/xxx/yyy']
        my_regex: '^.*/(.*)$'
        my_replace: '/\1'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - /sda1
  - /sdb1
  - /sdc1
  - /yyy
```

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: @user15574677 if this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the tick-button on the left side of the answer.